# Test ENV variable during development in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I've created the following config file for ENV variable and I want to test it in development(in dev cycle I want to test the prod and dev variable and get different configured values) ,how can I do that ?

```
module.exports = function () {

    switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
        case 'development':
            return
        {
            PORT : 3010
            UUID : '13bfbcf4-1f2f-11e5-b5f7-727283247c7f'
        };

        case 'production':
            return
        {
            PORT : 4000
            UUID : '3e30020a-1f2f-11e5-b5f7-727283247c7f'
        };

        default:
    }
};
```

in my server.js file I've using

```
config = require('./config');
...
 configs = new config();
```

But not sure how to test it and pass value since when I put after the above line `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development'` I got error,any idea how I can test locally the configs for prod and dev?

in addition this is recommended way to do this play with dev/prod?

Comment: lookup how to set enviroment vars in linux (or whatever), it's not part of node

Comment: @dandavis So how you suggest to test the config file ?I want that for example when you in "production" state you get the port 4000,Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems you're trying to reimplement [`config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config). Anyway, your config file contains invalid Javascript (missing comma's after the object properties).

Comment: `config = require('./config')(); console.log("using port: ", config.port)`

Comment: @dandavis-Thanks but which port I got in this case ,the dev? so just to verify I cannot modify somehow the env to be production just for testing?..

Comment: you can modify the env all you want, you just can't do so from inside node. you have to change it and then run node and your code sees the value you set. if you set it to "development", the (updated) comment code should log 3010

Comment: @dandavis- when I to what you describe I got error that port is not defined,I did config = require('./config')(); console.log("using port: ", config.port) ,any idea? the file that I require is exactly what i've posted in the question and this file is under the root(config.js) and the server.js file is also under the root ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order in which you do things is important: you need to set the environment variable before running your config function:

```
var config = require('./config');

process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

var configs = config();
```

If you want to set it externally, and provided that you're running some sort of Unix(-like) OS, start your app like this:

```
$ env NODE_ENV=production node server
```

I prefer using the [`config`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) module myself, which takes care of loading the proper configuration files etc.

Comment: Thanks I try to do what you suggest but Im getting error configs is not defined,any idea what could be the reason for this ?

Comment: @Mark sounds like your default case got selected.

Comment: what does it mean, I got the configs as undefined,what it can be ?

Comment: @Mark the default case in `config.js` returns nothing, so when it's selected (because the other cases didn't match) it will cause `configs` to be undefined.

Comment: Thanks but how can I overcome it and get the development or production ?any idea?